# Prompt user to enter two 3x3 int arrays and check equivalence

Tags: c++, arrays

Here is what I have come up with so far... I am so close with literally 1 error left for it to compile.

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

const int SIZE = 3;
bool equals(const int m1[][SIZE], const int m2[][SIZE])
{
    bool identical = true;
    for (int i=0; i < SIZE && identical; i++ )
    {
        if (m1[i] != m2[i]){
            identical = false;
        }
    }
    return identical = true;
}

void printArray(const int m1[], int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        cout << m1[i] << " ";
}

void printArray2(const int m2[], int size)  //not sure if I need this 2nd 
{                                           //void
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        cout << m2[i] << " ";
}


int main()
{
    string input1, input2;
    int const SIZE = 3;
    double inputnumber;

    int m2[SIZE];
    int m1[SIZE];

    cout << "Please enter the first array: " << endl;
    getline(cin, input1);
    stringstream ss (input1);
    ss >> inputnumber;

    cout << "Please enter the second array: " << endl;
    getline(cin, input2);
    stringstream si (input2);
    si>>inputnumber;

    for (int i=0; i< inputnumber ; ++i) {
        ss >> m1[i];}

    if (equals(m1, SIZE)){
        cout << "The two arrays are identical ! ";
    }
    else{
    cout << "The two arrays are NOT identical !";
    }
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Or at least I think that I am close... any help is much appreciated. 
My current error is coming up on the IF statement in the main function. I could have more mistakes as I am very very new to C++. Like I said please help me out if you can.

Comment: Can you post the error?

Comment: You don't need the second void BTW, it get's the value via a parameter so there is absolutely no reason not to use the other one.

Comment: Your code has some really serious basic flaws. The obvious is, that `if (equals(m1, SIZE)){` should be `if (equals(m1, m2)){`, but `m1` and `m2` aren't fitting for these either. Consider using a `std::vector<std::vector<int>` instead of  `const int m1[][SIZE]` passed to the `equals()` function.

Comment: And your code is only filling the second array (which is not a 3x3 but a 3x1 matrix BTW)

Comment: In your `equals` function, you can just return `identical` instead of `identical = true`. Also, you should have two arguments of type `int[][SIZE]`, not `int[]` as one argument and `SIZE` as the other (in the `if` statement in `main()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want code here it is , but if you want to practice I recommend you to implement error checking(incorrect format) in this code and to change the loops in my code into functions.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string inp;
    cout<<"Please enter an array of numbers in the following form\n"
          "(where N's are any numbers) :\n"
          "[N N N\nN N N\nN N N"<<endl;
    double m1[3][3],m2[3][3];
    for(short i=0;i<3;i++){
        cout<<"> ";
        if(i==0) cout<<"[ ";
        getline(cin,inp);
        stringstream inps(inp);
        for(short j=0;j<3;j++){
            inps>>m1[i][j];
        }
    }// Get the first array
    cout<<"Now enter the second array :\n";
    for(short i=0;i<3;i++){
        cout<<"> ";
        if(i==0) cout<<"[ ";
        getline(cin,inp);
        stringstream inps(inp);
        for(short j=0;j<3;j++){
            inps>>m2[i][j];
        }
    }// Get the second one
    bool not_equal=false;
    for(short i=0; i<3 && !not_equal ;i++)
        for(short j=0; j<3 && !not_equal ;j++)
            if(m1[i][j]!=m2[i][j])
                not_equal=true;// Test equality
    if(not_equal)
        cout<<"The two arrays you entered are not equal !!"<<endl;
    else
        cout<<"The two arrays you entered are EQUAL ."<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
 {
int size = 3;

int m2[size][size];
int m1[size][size];

cout << "Please enter the first array: " << endl;
for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
 {
  for(int j=0;j<size;j++)
   {
    cin >> m1[i][j];
   }
 }
cout << "Please enter the second array: " << endl;
for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
 {
  for(int j=0;j<size;j++)
   {
    cin >> m2[i][j];
   }
 }
int flag=1;
for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
 {
  for(int j=0;j<size;j++)
   {
    if(m2[i][j]!=m1[i][j])
     {
      flag=0;
     }
   }
 }
if(flag==1)
{
 cout <<"SAME"<<endl;
}
else if(flag==0)
{
 cout <<"NOT SAME"<<endl;
}
return 0;
```

}